# Is there a way to skin or create or mesh from a Point Cloud in blender?

Tags: python, blender, point-clouds

I am trying to use a .ply point cloud to create a mesh that I can then use for models or move into Unity. I found this article where someone created a python script for blender 2.6, but it is not working with blender 3.3. Does anyone know how to do this or have links or suggestions?

Here is the article of the way the other person did it for blender 2.6:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pointcloudskin/

Specifically I followed along with this article:
https://lesterbanks.com/2012/01/point-cloud-skinner-for-blender/
I added and enabled the pluggin, but the options did not appear in the scene tab of the properties window.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.